# How to load all CSS and JS from one html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The structure of my application is this:

[image]

On `webapp/assets/css` and `webapp/assets/js` I have my CSS and JavaScript  files, respectively.

On `WEB-APP/html/include/imports.html` I have the following links and script definitions:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png"
type="image/x-icon" />

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link id="bootstrap-rtl-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link
href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700,300"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link id="beyond-link" href="assets/css/beyond.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/demo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link id="skin-link" href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="assets/js/skins.min.js" ></script>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>

<!--Beyond Scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/beyond.js"></script>
```

Instead of putting all this information on each page I develop, I'd like to use something like (this is from login.html):

```
<link rel="imports" href="include/imports.html"></link>
```

I'm trying different relative paths but this is not working, both on the line above and on the file to "find" the CSS and JS files. Wasn't this supposed to work?

How can I, in a single line, with proper relative path to this file, include all CSS and JS to my pages?

Comment: you may consider to use **AMD** or **COMMON JS** loader like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: @Zamboney, is requirejs just for js or it handles css too?

Comment: its can work with [css](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css), did you work with requirejs before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are looking for some task runners such like gulp.js 
which I always use to make all scripts minified in a one file and all styles in one file ,it also helps in many other tasks

you can try to install in your project via :

```
npm install gulp --sav-dev
```

then you can use something like

```
gulp.src('js/*.js') // Matches all js files in js directory  
.pipe(minify()) // minify files
.pipe(gulp.dest('build')); // load them all in build file
```

for more info and tasks you can do with gulp see their [official docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md)